# gksu without root privileges

Tags: linux

In linux (ubuntu 9.10, in my case), is there any command similar to gksu but without root privileges? I've followed the instructions on pida's site and installed pida 0.6. When I run it using ./pida-run.py from terminal it starts fine. But when I made a gnome menu item and indicated the above command (with the correct location) to run it, it wouldn't run. So I was thinking if I add gksu alternative, maybe it'll work.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by gksu "without root privileges"? Isn't conferring root privileges all gksu does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `gksu` here..

Try changing the menu item's launcher type to "Application in Terminal" - maybe you'll see error messages come up.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Blorgbeard that the following won't solve your actual problem, but in the interest of answering the question asked, you can pre-pend the command field in the launcher with:

> gksu -u *username*

and the command should be run as the user *username*

Remember, the **su** means "switch user" despite the fact we mostly use it to become super user.

In general, when I have seen things work from a terminal but not from a launcher, some aspect of the environment is not being set the same way as in a terminal session.